# VisualStudio 2017 gray ellipsis below keyword

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone tell me what is VisualStudio 2017 trying to tell me with that grey ellipsis below keyword?

Neither placing the mouse over it or right-clicking it tells me why is this symbol showing there.

[image: VisualStudio2017 code image]
(gray ellipsis below "TValue" on the first line of the method)

Comment: maybe that the value is not initialized and used as out parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a code suggestion/refactoring hidden there telling you that what you have written can also be written in some other form while achieving the same functionality.

Till C# 7 i.e. VS 2017, this was the way of writing that but with C#7 [inline outs](https://nikhilagrawal.net/2017/03/19/csharp7_0_1_of_2/) you can reduce it to

```
return TryGetValue(key, out TValue value) ? value : defaultValue;
```

You can also declare it `var` which was not possible earlier. So you can write this as

```
return TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : defaultValue;
```

**How to achieve this**

Take your cursor to `...` and can see this suggestion in two ways

1. Press `Ctrl` + `.` 
   OR
2. A roslyn bulb will appear and you can click on it and the drop down will suggest you the same.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hint. Place your cursor on it, give it a second or two, and you should see a Roslyn lightbulb appear.

In this case, it's probably trying to show you that C# 7 syntax will allow you to declare out variables inline:

```cs
this.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value) ? value : defaultValue;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `out TValue value`? Of course, this is a feature I was not aware that I needed. It makes the code *less* readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a refactoring hint.

You can use `View.QuickActions` (default keyboard shortcut: `ctrl`+`.`) action while caret is above the ellipsis to see what options are there.